# 'git add .' is not working after merge command of two branches

Tags: git

I merged two branches. Now when I try to `git add .`, a folder simply is ignored by the command. So then I run 'git status' this is displayed in red - 'modified:   admin'.

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working d
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodul
#
#       modified:   admin (modified content)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

How do I commit the changes to admin?

Comment: Admin is a **submodule**!

Comment: I was in base directory. The problem was that the subfolder ADMIN had another git file. I had to go to admin directory first and commit my changes or I could simply delete the git. folder in admin directory, so it works directly under git. in base directory. 

So if you have the same problem check if the branch you merge, incudes of any git. repositories with in the folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `admin` is not a file

This message:

```
#       modified:   admin (modified content)
```

indicates that `admin` is a submodule.

It's a submodule in a dirty state - there are uncommitted changes within it. From the main repository there are no changes to commit, as the submodule's repository hasn't been changed, hence nothing happens if you try to commit with this scenario you do however recieve a warning that the submodule contains "modified content".

### How to commit the changes

The submodule needs to be updated for the main repository to be able to reference those changes i.e.:

```
cd admin
git commit -va
# review and then commit the changes
git push # important if you want to be able to access this change elsewhere

cd ..
git add admin
git commit admin -m "bumping admin submodule"
```

If the submodule is not your own code it's very likely this is *not* what you want to do - in which case please explain (by editing the question) the objective i.e. the purpose of making changes in a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If admin is the only file that you need to commit, then why don't you try `git add admin`?

As for why `git add .` doesn't work, what directory are you in when you run `git add .`? If you're in a directory other than the base directory of the repository, then admin would've been missed since it's in the base directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
git add admin
```

or

```
git add *
```

Finally, you can commit the added file:

```
git commit -a -m "Commit message"
```